# What is "Rolling Window" used for?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello~ all
Recently I do some research about Robot Navigation.
I'd like to find a way to save new map updated by Local Plan(Scan) while doing navigation.
I found a interesting parameter "Rolling Window"...but no idea how to use it.
Just know the definition as follows

---

http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

~/rolling_window (bool, default: false)
Whether or not to use a rolling window version of the costmap. If the static_map parameter is set to true, this parameter must be set to false.

---

If "Rolling Window" is a parameter that user can do navigation and discover unknown area.
Then we might can find some way to save the updated map.
I tried to killl "amcl" node and run "slam_gmapping" independently.
But...it's still failed cuz all new scanned info & static map will be cleaned.

Please share if you know...
(1) what's the correct meaning of "rolling window" and how to use it
(2) how to successfully saved new scanned info as a map file

Appreciation :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223880/what-is-%22rolling-window%22-used-for?/) by [Eric_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25481/eric_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Rolling window" means that you do not use the costmap to represent your complete environment, but only to represent your local surroundings (e.g. 5m x 5m around your robot). The costmap will then move along with your robot and will be updated by incoming sensor data.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akhilkathi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30211/akhilkathi/) on 2017-06-09**:
Does that mean if rolling_window=true
the costmap represent only the local surroundings centering our robot?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2017-06-12**:
Yes. Set to false to use it as a global map.

**Comment by [LucYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32184/lucyang/) on 2018-03-29**:
Can I increase the size of rolling window to help the robot locate itself better?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2018-05-15**:
No, rolling window maps are local maps and not used for localization.

**Comment by [pqLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/54468/pqlee/) on 2020-11-01**:
Can rolling_window param be used for local path planner without static map? thanks.